# FLURL 4.0 use Newtonsoft JSON Serializer on a single request

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonserializer, flurl

Referencing [Flurl Serializers](https://flurl.dev/docs/configuration/#serializers) it shows that Flurl 4.0 can use the Newtonsoft based serializer, but it is not clear to me how to do this for a single request. I need this to address a circular loop error in my request.

Answer (score 2):

Here is sample code to do that

```
// this is needed when serializing classes to prevent circular loop error
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
};
// create a Newtonsoft-based serializer for Flurl to use
var serializer = new Flurl.Http.Newtonsoft.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer(settings);

var result = await urlOrRequest
    // apply the serializer just to this request
    .WithSettings(settings => settings.JsonSerializer = serializer)
    .PostJsonAsync(data);
```

Comment: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` is global so all threads are affected.  Why not pass the settings into the [`NewtonsoftJsonSerializer constructor`](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/blob/363416c4e60911ccce4f82a5dc9012eab7e833a9/src/Flurl.Http.Newtonsoft/NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.cs#L19)?

Comment: Are you saying like this? 
.WithSettings(settings =>
    { settings.JsonSerializer =
        new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer(new JsonSerializerSettings
        { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
    })

Comment: Exactly.  Setting `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` will modify the global serializer settings used by `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` everywhere in your app.  If you want that, then great, but if you only want to use those settings for this particular request it seems safer to do `WithSettings(settings => { settings.JsonSerializer = new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer(new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore }); }`

Comment: This answer is correct (+1), I hope you don't mind that I reduced it quite a bit to focus only on the question asked :)